# OpenCV: Distance between fixed camera and an object

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, distance

I have a fixed camera so I know the distance between the camera to the ground, as well as the distance between the camera and the bottom line in the image (which is the floor).
I have an object in the image and I need to calculate the distance to it. However, the actual dimensions of the object are not available.

In the first image, the distance to the object is 75cm. In the second image the distance is 33cm.

How can I calculate the distances using the fixed camera? I found a few tutorials which used the focal length and the width of the object, however I cannot use it.
I can detect the object and have a bounding box around it.
Thanks

[image: Example 1 - distance to the object is 75cm]

[image: Example 2 - distance to the object is 33cm]

Comment: you need an "extrinsic" calibration, i.e. the transformation between camera-space and floor-space. then you can tell for a picture pixel where the viewing ray intersects the floor, and then you know where the box is (assuming it sits on the floor).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, thanks. Is there a guide how to create such transformation?

Comment: just lay down an aruco code.

Comment: Lazy idea : If you don't need accuracy well, you can assume the orientation of the camera.
e.g. looking your image, it seems that pitch angle and roll angle is roughly 0.